# How do you read csv without the absolute path ( python 3.10 panda)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

so i put the python file and the csv file in the same folder.
i know that its usually pd.read_csv("C://Users/XXX//XXX//XXX//XXX//Data.csv")

how can i make it into "pd.read_csv('Data.csv')"

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `__file__`:

```
import os.path

pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Data.csv")
```